# Explaining a limit in calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across this:

> If $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f\left( 1+h \right)}{h}=1$ and $f(x)$ has a derivative at $x=1$ then:
>   $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left( 1 \right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left( 1+h \right)}{h}-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left( 1+h \right)-f\left( 1 \right)}{h}$$

I don't understand why this is true. Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Jason : You had some complicated code involving \underset and \mathop where you only needed \lim_{h\to 0}.  I changed it.  In the one instance where it's "inline" rather than "displayed", I changed it to \lim\limits_{h\to 0}.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok, Thanks :) I don't know TeX I just use a program to generate it - I guess that's why it's messy sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of one of the basic limit laws:

> If $\lim\limits_{t\to a} F(t)$ exists and $\lim\limits_{t\to a}G(t)$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{t\to a}\Bigl( F(t)-G(t)\Bigr)$ exists, and
>   $$\lim_{t\to a}\Bigl(F(t)-G(t)\Bigr) = \lim_{t\to a}F(t) - \lim_{t\to a}G(t).$$

So, we are assuming that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)}{h}\ \text{exists.}$$
We are also assuming that $f(x)$ has a derivative at $1$; that means that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\ \text{exists.}$$

Therefore, 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left( \frac{f(1+h)}{h} - \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\right)\ \text{exists}$$
and moreover,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(1+h)}{h} - \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)}{h} - \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$$
by the limit law quoted above, with $F(h) = \frac{f(1+h)}{h}$ and $G(h) = \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$.

Now just notice that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{f(1+h)}{h} - \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} &= \frac{f(1+h)-(f(1+h)-f(1))}{h}\\
 &= \frac{f(1+h)-f(1+h)+f(1)}{h}\\
 &= \frac{f(1)}{h},
\end{align*}$$
giving the equality you have when you put everything together.

That means that
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1)}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(1+h)}{h} - \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\right)\\
&= \left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)}{h}\right) - \left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\right)\\
&= 1 - f'(1),
\end{align*}$$
since your assumption is that the first limit equals $1$, and by definition the second limit is the derivative at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look as a useful trait but it is true.
We have:
$$\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\ \frac{f\left( 1 \right)}{h}=\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\ \frac{f \left( 1+h \right) - f\left( 1+h \right)+f\left( 1 \right)}{h}=\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\ \frac{f \left( 1+h \right) - (f\left( 1+h \right)-f\left( 1 \right))}{h}=$$$$=\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\ \frac{f\left( 1+h \right)}{h}-\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\ \frac{f\left( 1+h \right)-f\left( 1 \right)}{h}$$

Comment: Thank you :) I agree I think it not useful very often but it is for a particular problem I am trying to solve...